# How to properly manage password managers across subdomains

Tags: html, forms, password-manager

Imagine you have a site that uses some oauth solution. In this case, you might have urls like signin.mycompany.com for login, then usecase1.mycompany.com for one use case, and so on... When you save your pwd, password managers (like the built-in solutions from Safari/Chrome/Firefox) will usually save the password under the name signin.mycompany.com ([email]) -or something similar.

If the user forgets the password or changes it, the chance that the form for the pwd change / reset are on different subdomains is relatively big. Is there any way to set the name the pwd is saved under to "mycompany.com ([email]), so that all subdomains will use and save the same entry? Or at least find some solution that will behave properly?

I know this might sound like a security vulnerability, but in such cases often sites have specific CORS policies to allow subdomains to access resources, so generalizing password manager (as long as it is controlled from serverside) should not be a big deal...

Comment: Unfortunately, the use/deployment of software in an enterprise IT environment is somewhat out-of-scope here per the [help/on-topic]; however Stack Overflow's sister site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) is likely to have folks who can answer this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with enterprise stuff. It can be the keychain app on Mac, or the built-in pwd-managers in Chrome/Firefox...

Comment: In that case, the use of software in an end-user context is also off-topic and would be better fit on [Super User](https://superuser.com)

Comment: "*Is there any way to set the name the pwd is saved under to "mycompany.com ([email]), so that all subdomains will use and save the same entry?*" The answer to this is *highly specific* to the implementation of the individual password manager - they all function differently from one another and even then there are likely several different types of configurations users or their enterprise administrators can make to enable/disable such behavior dependent on the assessed risk of such a mechanism.

Comment: @esqew, still they rely on similar things like "autocomplete=username and autocomplete=current-password" html tags, else autocompletion would not work. Comparing Chrome to Safari, they store the same key (site, username), and username is controlled by the tag autocomplete=username, else it does not work... So yes, there is some sort of standard. If there is a rfc or similar document, it would be great to see the link, maybe there is some way of controlling something...

Comment: Just because something does not have an `autocomplete` attribute doesn't necessarily mean that "*autocompletion would not work*". My local copy of 1Password completes login fields that lack these attributes all the time. While there is a standard, it's not necessarily relied upon.

Comment: I still consider it a valid question, since the html standard has some controls that suggest such things. I found this: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-name

Still, no concrete Information on how clients should behave with pwd stuff...

Comment: @esqew, btw, if a site does not properly set the current-password and new-password tags, and the browser cannot infere the meaning from the other html tags, a pwd change might not be handled well. These tags should guarantee that pwd-managers can handle it properly...